# Applescript for automating MS Word for Mac feature: add quote mark wrapper to unformatted text paste

Tags: applescript, ms-office, automator, script

The post below from 2011 gave a really good script for pasting unformatted text into Word for Mac.

[How can one create a shortcut for pasting unformatted text in Microsoft Word 2008 for Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9859/how-can-one-create-a-shortcut-for-pasting-unformatted-text-in-microsoft-word-200)

I'm a student, using this to help with quoting in essays, but I have no experience writing apple script. I've found a few scripts that wrap selected text in " marks (e.g. https://www.macworld.com/article/2038095/5-automator-workflows-everyone-should-have.html ) but have no idea how they could be integrated with the first script so that the unformatted text that is pasted has " marks wrapped around it.

Is that something someone could help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first script and add a line to it to integrate it, like so:

```
try
    set theClip to Unicode text of (the clipboard as record)
    --add this line to the original script
    set theClip to "\"" & theClip & "\""
    tell application "Microsoft Word" to tell selection to type text text theClip
end try
```

That should do it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much; it makes a surprising difference to the fiddliness of note-taking at the literature review stage!